# How to add some extra spacing between two paragraphs in ConTeXt?

Tags: spacing, context

I've set up inter-paragraph spacing for a ConTeXt document but in-between two specific paragraphs, I'd like to have some extra spacing. About 1 inch. In LaTeX I'd use `\vspace{1in}`. What is the command I use do add this?

Comment: @ana I reread the question and found that :) In any case, I think it's better to use “symbolic” like `\blank[big]` or `\blank[medium]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha. The `blank` command.

`\blank[1in]`